# Regex not working for some of the user input

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to build a regex for the following cases:

**Split the input by ',' excluding the input that has a number before and after ',' or only before ','**

**For example:**
**Input:** test input, val input, input 1, input 2, input 3,4

**Output:** ['test input','val input','input 1','input 2','input 3,4']

```
$input_values = "test input, val input, input 1, input 2, input 3,4";
$regex = '/(?<!\d)\,/m';
$subst = '~';
$initial_input = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $input_values);
var_dump($initial_input);
```

The code that is mentioned here displays the output:

```
['test input','val input', 'input 1, input 2', 'input 3,4']
```

It doesn't split **input 1, input 2**

Comment: Try `'/(?<!\d(?=,\d)),/'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It indeed works, thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'/(?<!\d(?=,\d)),/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HPnZeJ/1)

[image]

It matches a `,` that is not preceded with a digit that is followed with a `,` and a digit.

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6QnmE):

```
$input_values = "test input, val input, input 1, input 2, input 3,4";
$regex = '/(?<!\d(?=.\d)),/';
$subst = '~';
$initial_input = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $input_values);
print_r($initial_input);
// => test input~ val input~ input 1~ input 2~ input 3,4
```

Comment: Thanks again for the deep explanation